# No Content Exception Error in Zoho Api v2 in php sdk

Tags: php, api, zoho

Hi I hope everybody is doing well

I am trying to add leads to Zoho CRM using API v2, now for that, if the user already there I will update its record if a user is not there I will create a new record into it, right now I am finding out a way to handle the exception error when there is not any user in CRM it displays this line

```
Fatal error: Uncaught zcrmsdk\crm\exception\ZCRMException Caused by:'No Content' in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmint2\vendor\zohocrm\php-sdk\src\crm\api\response\BulkAPIResponse.php(61) #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmint2\vendor\zohocrm\php-sdk\src\crm\api\response\CommonAPIResponse.php(76): zcrmsdk\crm\api\response\BulkAPIResponse->handleForFaultyResponses() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmint2\vendor\zohocrm\php-sdk\src\crm\api\response\CommonAPIResponse.php(67): zcrmsdk\crm\api\response\CommonAPIResponse->processResponse() #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmint2\vendor\zohocrm\php-sdk\src\crm\api\response\BulkAPIResponse.php(47): zcrmsdk\crm\api\response\CommonAPIResponse->__construct('HTTP/1.1 204 \r\n...', 204) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmint2\vendor\zohocrm\php-sdk\src\crm\api\APIRequest.php(148): zcrmsdk\crm\api\response\BulkAPIResponse->__construct('HTTP/1.1 204 \r\n...', 204) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmint2\vendor\zohocrm\php-sdk\src\crm\api\handler\MassEntityAPIHandler.php(327): zcrmsdk\crm\api\APIRequest->getBulkAPIResponse() #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\crmint2\vendor\zoh in C:\xampp\htdocs\crmint2\vendor\zohocrm\php-sdk\src\crm\api\response\BulkAPIResponse.php on line 61
```

Now I have tried try and catch statement as well but it stucks here and crashes the application, I am looking forward to someone who had gone through this and was successful in implementing it

Comment: Can you post your try-catch block code.

Comment: $moduleIns=ZCRMRestClient::getInstance()->getModuleInstance("Leads");  //To get module instance

 
 $response= $moduleIns->searchRecordsByEmail($Email,1,200);  //To get module records that match the Email address
 try
 {
  echo "no code here";
 }
 catch(ZCRMException $ex){

  echo $ex->getMessage(); // To get ZCRMException error message

 }

Comment: you should move code for getting module and searching recording in try block and also make sure ZCRMException class is imported.

Comment: Thanks it helps me ! thats my code by the way there is still an error which i am not sure why it is happening

Comment: use zcrmsdk\crm\setup\restclient\ZCRMRestClient;
 use zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMModule;
 use zcrmsdk\oauth\ZohoOAuth;
 use zcrmsdk\crm\crud\ZCRMRecord;
 use zcrmsdk\crm\exception\ZCRMException;

 require 'vendor/autoload.php';
 include 'config.php';
 try
  {
   $a = ZCRMRestClient::initialize($configuration);
   $moduleIns=ZCRMRestClient::getInstance()->getModuleInstance("Leads"); 
   $Email  = "Abd"; 
   $response =  $moduleIns->searchRecordsByEmail($Email,1,200);

   
  }
 catch (ZCRMException $ex) 

 {
   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($ex->getMessage());
   echo "</pre>";
 }

Comment: is it the same error now? try one more thing add another catch block with Catch(\Exception $e), see if it works?

Comment: Thanks bro, i did a small change in sdk code! actually i was not calling zoho exception class

Comment: you can post your solution as answer too.it may help somebody missing the same step someday.